# json_decode returns NULL, json_last_error_msg gives "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Tags: php, json

The file looks fine when read into my editor.

```
$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file.json');
$json =  json_decode($file, true);
var_dump($json); // null
echo json_last_error_msg(); //Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

There isn't much out there on what this error message means.

Comment: Could you please post your `file.json` ? because `json_decode` fails to decode your json string from file.

Comment: It means your file doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: In case someone reached here. "I was facing the same issue. I found that I was reading `1024` characters and the whole line length was more than that. And it was causing the issue. Then updating the length sovled the issue". Accepted answer didn't help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can remove the [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), PCRE supports the POSIX notation for character classes [`[:cntrl:]`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)

```
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json);
echo json_last_error_msg();
```

Comment: In general, this is wrong approach. Just imagine that you have the following string: "hello\nworld" where \n is unescaped  (0x0a) char. `preg_replace` will fix it, although you will remain with "helloworld". A code which produces json-encoded string should be fixed instead.