# How to access certain part of a nested JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access the content of "text" in the following code. Actually I have asked almost the same question before and it was solved perfectly. [How to access certain part of a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437592/how-to-access-certain-part-of-a-json) However, when I use the same method on this JSON, it doesn't work.

```php
$test = 
'{
    "username":"lon",
    "event":{
        "saved_response":"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion for teaching means loving your job. Doing with all your heart. Teachers who are passionate can inspire pupils to love learning. Passionate teachers create an effective learning environment and increase learning potential of\\nstudents.\"}]}"
    },
    "event_source":"server"
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
$jevent = json_decode($jarray['event']['saved_response'], true);
var_dump($jevent);
echo $jevent['parts'][0]['text'];
```

The output is NULL and I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: null result from json_decode can indicate a decoding error, if you print `json_last_error_msg()` it outputs: `Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded` (for me).

Comment: The `\\n` appears to be the problem.

Comment: So how can I access the content? I can't change the content of the text because I'm required to access it.

Comment: If you strip the control characters from your substringified JSON, like here, it appears to decode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699371 , assume the encoding isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

The tried and tested `json_decode(json_encode($test), true);`
Does the job for me. Cheers!

```
$test = 
'{
"username":"lon",
"event":{
    "saved_response":"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion for teaching means loving your job. Doing with all your heart. Teachers who are passionate can inspire pupils to love learning. Passionate teachers create an effective learning environment and increase learning potential of\\nstudents.\"}]}"
},
"event_source":"server"
}';

$jarray = json_decode(json_encode($test), true);

$jarray = explode('"',$jarray);

print_r($jarray[14]);
```

Comment: A word of explanation: this escapes quotes, making the string parseable.

Comment: Do you mean replace`json_decode($test, true);`with`json_decode(json_encode($test), true);`? It doesn't work for me and I get the error message `Warning: Illegal string offset 'event'`

Comment: just print the results of  `json_decode(json_encode($test), true)` you dont need to decode it further

Comment: @RedBottle But I need to access the content of the text. What should I do next?

Comment: handle it like you would handle a normal array after that

Comment: @RedBottle I tried `echo $jarray['event']['saved_response']['parts'][0]['text'];` It still didn't work.

Comment: if you really just want the "text" try exploding it like so `$jarray = json_decode(json_encode($test), true); $jarray = explode('"',$jarray); print_r($jarray[14]);`